# Override __add__method

Tags: python, list, class, addition

I'm trying to override the `__add__` method so that the duplicate will not be added. What went wrong with my code?

```
class Ulist(UserList):

    def __init__(self,value=[]):
        UserList.__init__(self)
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self,addvalue):
        for x in addvalue:
            if x in self.value:
                print("It already exists")
            else:
                return self.value.__add__(addvalue)
```

If `Ulist=[1,2,3]`, and I do `Ulist.__add__([3])`, I am expecting a message of "**it already exists**". But I got `[1,2,3,3]`.

Comment: If you really initialize `Ulist` as `[1, 2, 3]`, then it's just a list and you no longer have a class by that name in your namespace.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is an object in Python, including classes, modules, lists, etc. You access objects by the name they are bound to.

When you write `class Ulist(UserList): ...`, you bind a class object to the name `Ulist`. Since classes are regular objects, you can do something like

```
Vlist = Ulist
x = Vlist()
```

This will produce the same result as if you had called `Ulist` directly, since the first assignment just binds the class once to another name.

When you subsequently do `Ulist = [1, 2, 3]`, you discard the class object that the name `Ulist` was originally bound to, and bind it to a list object instead. This is because an expression in square brackets is always interpreted as a plain `list`.

To create an instance of `Ulist` the class, you have to call the initializer:

```
x = Ulist([1, 2, 3])
```

Now the operation `x + [3]` should print what you originally expected. Note that you aren't normally supposed to call special methods like `__add__` directly. Either use `+`, or more rarely, [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add).

Another thing to keep in mind is that [`UserList`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#userlist-objects) already exposes the underlying `list` via the [`data`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.UserList.data) attribute. Your `value` attribute is overkill at this point and actually prevents you from using all the other nice features of `UserList`. A better implementation would look something like

```
class Ulist(UserList):

    def __init__(self, value=[]):
        super().__init__(value)

    def __add__(self, addvalue):
        for x in addvalue:
            if x in self:
                print(f"{x!r} already exists")
            else:
                return super().__add__(addvalue)
```

All in all, though, what you are probably looking for is `set`.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

you have initialize `Ulist` as variable so it will act as object of list:

to work with your code you need to instantiate the object of the class, see below example

```
class Ulist():

    def __init__(self, value=[]):

        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, addvalue):
        for x in addvalue:
            if x in self.value:
                print("It already exists")
            else:
                return self.value.__add__(addvalue)


o = Ulist(value=[1, 2, 3])

o.__add__([3])

print o.value
```

**output**

```
It already exists
[1, 2, 3]
```